# i keep gettin ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a parser for a website, because I need all the content from this website. Here is my code so far:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeauitfulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def main():
    print(get_html('http://marryme.md'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have installed bs4 in my virtual environment and I see in my pip list that is successfully installed. Also I found the bs4 folder in my `virtualenv` directory, but when I run my code I keep getting this error.

Comment: `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`?..

Comment: Give us more details, please. Where exactly is bs4 folder in virtualenv directory? How do you run the script? Does it have a shebang line and what line?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to activate the virtualenv first:

```
. venv/bin/activate
python script.py
```

or explicitly specify the Python interpreter:

```
venv/bin/python script.py
```

Of course replace `venv` with the name/path to your virtualenv.